# Show an AlertDialog just for one time in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hy Guys.
I have an alert dialog which starts automaticaly by initState but this AlertDialog has to be shown just one time for the user.
this is my code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      showAlertDialogue();
    });
  }

  showAlertDialogue() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: InfoAlert(),//this is the AlertDialog from another file
    );
  }
```

any help to make this dialog just one time dialog?

Comment: Do you mean one time ever (like terms and conditions) or one time while the screen is active?

Comment: I mean when user go to a specific Page, this AlertDialog appears, so I want this AlertDialog appears just for the first time user see this AlertDialog, if user come back to this page, the AlertDialog wont appear again.

Comment: ah ok, check out the SharedPreferences package then. That package manages persistent storage in a map-like structure. Like this you can access the data even after the app was closed and opened again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies:

```
shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2
```

Add this import in your page:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Update your code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    final int dialogOpen = prefs.getInt('dialog_open') ?? 0;
    if (dialogOpen == 0) {//show dialog for one time only      
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
        showAlertDialogue();
        prefs.setInt("dialog_open", 1);
      });
    }
   });
  }
```

Comment: thanks But I think it miss something, I get: "The await expression can only be used in an async function."

Comment: If I add async into initstate I get error: _IfProfilePageState.initState() returned a Future.

Comment: Hello now the code work but the Alert Dialog doesnt appears... where I need to edit times etc.. ?

Comment: @TiziDev   can you post full code for dialog and page ?

Comment: I tried it and it showed for first time. Then on next time it didn't show because this was you asked for.

Comment: you need to clear app data or reinstall your app to see it for first time or you can set "dialog_open" to 0 or remove this check dialogOpen==0 temporarily